# How to use AJAX to communicate between js and php while using a modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am having a lot of trouble learning how to successfully use ajax.  On the project that I am working on to learn this, I am selecting between a variety of people on a chart.  When I select the person, I click their button and update the database.  However, I need to be able to populate a modal in order to send a message to that person.  I have been trying to use ajax to do this as all I need is the one $userid variable that is chosen.

My code is below, and if there is an easier way to do this without using ajax that would be great as well!

**php**

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['usrid'])) {
    $whatineed = $_POST['usrid'];
?>
div modal stuff
<?php>
```

**js**

```
$(".selectLink").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var _self = this;

        $.post(
             site_url("user/update"),  
            { 
                usrid: $(this).attr("usrid") 
            }, function(){
                $('#Contact').modal({show:true, backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
            }
        )   
        return false;
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is that modal pop-up?

Comment: explain `populate a modal in order to send a message to that person`. Code you run within ajax callback will only work on current page

Comment: its a modal popup (from bootstrap) that allows you to send a message to another user

Answer (score 1):

I have no chance to check the code, but I will try to give you a whole picture:

**update.php:**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['usrid'])) {
    $whatineed = "The updater have an user ID " . $_POST['usrid']; 
    } else {
    $whatineed = "The updater have nothing to do, because an user ID have not been received.";
    }
    echo($whatineed);// this is the message TO modal
?>
```

**persons.html**

```
<a userid="abc1" class="selectLink" href="#">click me to start update</a>
<div id="Contact" title="I have a message from the update scrtipt">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

**persons.js**

```
$(".selectLink").click(function (e) {
    var userid = $(e.target).attr("userid");
    var _self = this;
    $.post(site_url("user/update.php"), {
        usrid: usrid
    }, function (data) { //message FROM update.php
        var dlg = $('#Contact'), 
            txt = $('#Contact p');// or txt = dlg.find("p");
        txt.html(data);
        dlg.dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 150,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    })
    return false;
});
```

One more time -- it is just a point. This parts must be adjusted and debugged in your whole code.